Nested navigator - get active route name
my navigation is as follows
RootStack > TabNavigation > HomeStack > { home screens }
and am using this way to get the current rout name
// Get the route name
const RouteName = () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
    return routeName
}

it's getting me the Homestack but it can't react it's screen how can I get them also
Tried this not working ?
const RouteName = () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
    return routeName
}

